# Visual Studio Express and Macro Assembler includes

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-express, masm

I have both Visual Studio Express 2012 and Vicual C++ Express 2010. I get the same result with both of their 32 bit MASM compilers (ml.exe). *I don't know, but I suspect non-express users might have the same issues.*

I'm trying to compile a small program with MASM. Apparently I need to include `masm32rt.inc`. The compiler complains that it cannot find such a file, and indeed I don't seem to have it on my system. After some search, I managed to find a version of that file, but it turned out to be just more `include`-s and `includelib`-s of files I don't have.

I tried `include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc`, `include \masm32\include\windows.inc`, `include windows.inc`, and `include masm32rt.inc`. I tried compiling them with the visual studio express command prompt for both 2010 and 2012 with `> ml test.asm`. I tried searching for those files and I don't have them on my pc. I do have some (30 or so) `.inc` files like `macamd64.inc` and `mm.inc`, but none of them seem to contain what I need: declarations of the Windows functions and constants.

Is there something I'm missing? Google didn't offer much help. Most tutorials assume I have those files. But then again most tutorials begin with instructions to donwload MASM from [masm32.com](http://www.masm32.com/). Can't I use any of the MASM compilers that I already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ml is just the Assembler.  Unless you want to reinvent the wheel and create all includes and import libs, then you need to install masm32.  It includes needed includes, import libs, structs, equates etc... It will make your life much easier

Comment: Too bad. Although I can use the includes and compile the samples provided by the masm32.com installation with the ml.exe compilers that come from Visual Studio. It's apparently the same, or almost the same compiler. The question is, then, why don't the masm32.com people have the includes and samples available as a separate download, instead of forcing me to install something in root:\masm32 :(

Answer (score -2):

The code you're trying to compile uses *MASM32* macros and/or *MASM32* library. Meaning that it was built for *MASM32*. *MASM32* macros and library are not available in *Visual Studio*, since *MASM32* is a diferent *MASM*-compatible (to an extent) compiler. You'll have to at least have the required include files in order to successfully compile that code.

Comment: MASM32 uses the same exact Assembler (ML) and Linker as VS.  It IS MASM on steroids.  MASM32 CAN be used with VS.  MASM32 contains macros, prototypes, structure definitions, import libs etc, to make life easier.  You do not have to use it, but you will have to create prototypes for the api calls, import libs, structures, and equates.